# Improper integrals in a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I have these exercises about improper integrals in $\mathbb{R^2}$:

a.$\iint_U (x+y)^{-1}e^{-x^2-y^2} dx dy$, and b.$\iint_U (x+y)^{2}e^{-x^2-y^2} dx dy$ (in the case b. I have to compute the value of integral),
where $U=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}: 0<x<y\}$.
For a. I tried to divide $U$ in two subsets $U_1$ and $U_2$ so that I could study separate convergences near $(0,0)$ and "to $\infty$". To study near $(0,0)$, I pick $R>0$ such that $U_1 \subset B(0,R)$ and then $\iint_{U_1} (x+y)^{-1}e^{-x^2-y^2} dx dy \leq\iint_{B(0,R)} (x+y)^{-1}e^{-x^2-y^2} dx dy$ and the latter can be studied with polar coordinate: $\int_{0}^{R}e^{-\rho^2}d\rho\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)}d\theta<+\infty$. Is this a good argument? And how could I study problem "to $\infty$"? And for the case b. (in which I have no problems near $(0,0$)) how can I compute the integral?

Answer (score 1):

Both integrals can be computed. For the first integral, let $U(\epsilon)$ be the part of $U$ of all points $(x,y)$ with distance from $0$ bigger than $\epsilon$. Then polar coordinates can be used in both cases, and we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&
\iint_U \frac 1{x+y}\;e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\; dx\; dy
\\
&\qquad=
\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0}
\iint_{U(\epsilon)} \frac 1{x+y}\;e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\; dx\; dy
\\
&\qquad=
\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0}
\int_{t\in(\pi/4,\;\pi/2)}
\int_{r\in(\epsilon,\infty)}
\frac 1{r\cos t+r\sin t}\;e^{-r^2}\; r\; dr\; dt
\\
&\qquad=
\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0}
\left(\int_{t\in(\pi/4,\;\pi/2)}
\frac 1{\cos t+\sin t}\;
dt
\right)
\left(
\int_{(\epsilon,\infty)}
e^{-r^2}\; dr
\right)
\\
&\qquad=
\left(\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}
\frac 1{\sqrt 2}
\frac 1{\sin (t+\pi/4)}\;
dt
\right)
\underbrace{
\left(
\int_0^\infty
e^{-r^2}\; dr
\right)}_{=\sqrt \pi/2}
\\
&\qquad=
\frac 1{\sqrt 2}
\log(1+\sqrt 2)
\cdot
\frac 12\sqrt \pi
\ ,
\\[4mm]
&
\iint_U (x+y)^2\;e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\; dx\; dy
\\
&\qquad=
\int_{t\in(\pi/4,\;\pi/2)}
\int_{r\in(0,\infty)}
(r\cos t+r\sin t)^2\;e^{-r^2}\; r\; dr\; dt
\\
&\qquad=
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}
(\cos t+\sin t)^2\;dt
\int_0^\infty
r^2\;e^{-r^2}\; r\; dr
\\
&\qquad=
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}
(1+\sin 2t)\;dt
\int_0^\infty
u
\;e^{-u}\; \frac 12\; du
\\
&\qquad=
\frac 14(\pi+2)\cdot \frac 12\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We have used the substitution $u=r^2$, and the integral from $u\; e^{-u}$ is easily done using partial integration.

---

Numerical checks, here using the numerical integral of pari/gp:

```
? intnum(y=0, 1000, intnum(x=0, y, exp(-x^2-y^2) / (x+y)))
%7 = 0.55231899020403252238290082131158922557
? sqrt(2*Pi)/4 * log(1+sqrt(2))
%8 = 0.55231898843403327845821770848872247865
? 
? intnum(y=0, 100, intnum(x=0, y, exp(-x^2-y^2) * (x+y)^2))
%9 = 0.64269908169252333785385729214774221184
? (Pi+2)/8
%10 = 0.64269908169872415480783042290993786052
```